# Is that possible to have multiple rules function in single Request class?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation, laravel-5

**I have request class like below.**

```
class CategoryRequest extends Request
{
    public function response(array $errors){
        return \Redirect::back()->withErrors($errors)->withInput();
    }

    public function authorize()
    {
        return false;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'Category' => 'required|unique:tblcategory|max:25|min:5'
        ];
    }
}
```

There is rules function.

In the controller, there are multiple methods that have Request as a Parameter. Most of them vary in the validation point of view. I mean, if I am admin,. I can update 4 fields. If I am manager, I can update 3 and if I am normal user, I can update 2. So validation will change according to roles.

**Is that possible to have multiple rules function in Request class ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use here any conditions you want, so you you could do something like this:

```
public function rules()
{
    $rules = [];
    if (Auth::user()->isAdmin()) {
       $rules['Category'] = '...';
    } 
    elseif (Auth::user()->isManager()) {
       $rules['Category'] = '...';
    }        

    return $rules;
}
```

Of course you need to create `isAdmin` and `isManager` in your `User` model

Comment: Will it be something like `$rules[] = 'Category' => 'required|unique:tblcategory|max:25|min:5'; ?

Comment: Yeah, you can put here any rules you want, same as in your example

Comment: I tried this `$rules = [];
        if(\Auth::user()->RoleID == \App\Enumeration\Role\RoleType::Admin) {
            $rules[] =  'Category' => 'required|unique:tblcategory|max:25|min:5';
        }` and got error: **syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)**

Comment: I've updated my answer, you can put `Category` here inside rules, so it could be `$rules['Category'] = 'required|unique:tblcategory|max:25|min:5';`